# Override function call in VxWorks

Tags: unit-testing, vxworks

My problem is the following. I have a code unit composed of various c files, say for example

- file1.c
- file2.c
- file3.c

that are all compiled with GCC to a unique object "object.o", which in turn is then linked with other objects to give at the end the executable "application.out", running on VxWorks.

Since I'm doing unit testing on "object.o", my need is to stimulate all the possible ways through the code. Specifically, there are situations where I should have mock functions executed instead of original ones in order to simulate error occurrences.
Suppose for example that there is a function "func_caller" that I'm trying to test that, at some point in the execution, makes a call to another function "func_called" (declared as static).

Since I DON'T WANT TO MODIFY THE ORIGINAL CODE, I wonder if there is a way to manipulate the instruction pointers in such a way that when "func_called" is called, it actually executes another mock function "func_called_mock" and the caller "func_caller" does not notice anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The most direct method of overriding function calls would be to use VxWorks's load time linking. Consider the following source:

file1.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int function1 (void);

int function1 ()
{
    printf ("function1 called\n");

    return 1;
}
```

file2.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int function2 (void);

int function2 ()
{
    printf ("function2 called\n");

    return 2;
}
```

file3.c:

```
int function1 (void);
int function2 (void);

int function3 (void);

int function3 ()
{
    function1 ();
    function2 ();

    return 0;
}
```

mock.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int function1 (void);
int function2 (void);

int function1 ()
{
    printf ("mock function1 called\n");

    return 1;
}

int function2 ()
{
    printf ("mock function2 called\n");

    return 2;
}
```

When you load an object, its functions are added to the global symbol table.

```
-> ld < file1.o
value = 273740816 = 0x1050f410
-> lkup "function"
function1                 0x108b0000 text     (file1.o)
value = 0 = 0x0
->
```

When you load an object that uses functions already in the symbol table, each call will be immediately resolved to the last address associated with that symbol in the table.

```
-> ld < file2.o
value = 292535232 = 0x116fbbc0
-> ld < file3.o
value = 292537592 = 0x116fc4f8
-> lkup "function"
function1                 0x108b0000 text     (file1.o)
function2                 0x108d0000 text     (file2.o)
function3                 0x108f0000 text     (file3.o)
value = 0 = 0x0
-> l function3
            function3:
0x108f0000  55                      PUSH           EBP
0x108f0001  89 e5                   MOV            EBP, ESP
0x108f0003  56                      PUSH           ESI
0x108f0004  57                      PUSH           EDI
0x108f0005  e8 f6 ff fb ff          CALL           function1
0x108f000a  e8 f1 ff fd ff          CALL           function2
0x108f000f  31 c0                   XOR            EAX, EAX
0x108f0011  5f                      POP            EDI
0x108f0012  5e                      POP            ESI
0x108f0013  89 ec                   MOV            ESP, EBP
value = 0 = 0x0
-> function3
function1 called
function2 called
value = 0 = 0x0
->
```

Although `l()` helpfully displays function names, no symbols are actually loaded into memory with the object. Instead, a call to the last address associated with the function is loaded. So, a previously loaded function may be overridden by loading another function of the same name.

```
-> unld "file3.o"
value = 0 = 0x0
-> ld < mock.o
value = 292537592 = 0x116fc4f8
-> ld < file3.o
value = 292539496 = 0x116fcc68
-> lkup "function"
function1                 0x108f0000 text     (mock.o)
function1                 0x108b0000 text     (file1.o)
function2                 0x108f0020 text     (mock.o)
function2                 0x108d0000 text     (file2.o)
function3                 0x10910000 text     (file3.o)
value = 0 = 0x0
-> l function3
            function3:
0x10910000  55                      PUSH           EBP
0x10910001  89 e5                   MOV            EBP, ESP
0x10910003  56                      PUSH           ESI
0x10910004  57                      PUSH           EDI
0x10910005  e8 f6 ff fd ff          CALL           function1
0x1091000a  e8 11 00 fe ff          CALL           function2
0x1091000f  31 c0                   XOR            EAX, EAX
0x10910011  5f                      POP            EDI
0x10910012  5e                      POP            ESI
0x10910013  89 ec                   MOV            ESP, EBP
value = 0 = 0x0
-> function3
mock function1 called
mock function2 called
value = 0 = 0x0
->
```

Note that for this method to work, the called and calling functions cannot be compiled into the same object. You might also note that the addresses to be called don't match those in the symbol table. This is the result of executing the above in VxSim. The VxSim loader actually calls the loader of the underlying operating system. So, these addresses don't match those in the symbol table and the assembly reflects the underlying Pentium architecture on which WorkBench is being run.

A function call may also be overridden by directly manipulating the address to be called in memory. This method is going to be implementation dependent. Below, this is demonstrated for source compiled for PPC using the gcc -mlongcall option. This has been run on an actual target, not VxSim.

```
-> ld < file1.o
value = 33538216 = 0x1ffc0a8 = function1 + 0x498
-> ld < file2.o
value = 33548336 = 0x1ffe830 = function2 + 0x80
-> ld < mock.o
value = 33549600 = 0x1ffed20 = function2 + 0x570
-> ld < file3.o
value = 33550744 = 0x1fff198 = function2 + 0x9e8
->
-> lkup "function"
function1                 0x01ffbef8 text     (mock.o)
function1                 0x01ffbc10 text     (file1.o)
function2                 0x01ffbf58 text     (mock.o)
function2                 0x01ffe7b0 text     (file2.o)
function3                 0x01ffe558 text     (file3.o)
value = 0 = 0x0
->
-> function3
mock function1 called
mock function2 called
value = 0 = 0x0
->
-> l function3 
                        function3:
0x1ffe558  9421ffe8    stwu        r1,-24(r1)
0x1ffe55c  7c0802a6    mfspr       r0,LR
0x1ffe560  93a1000c    stw         r29,12(r1)
0x1ffe564  93c10010    stw         r30,16(r1)
0x1ffe568  93e10014    stw         r31,20(r1)
0x1ffe56c  9001001c    stw         r0,28(r1)
0x1ffe570  7c3f0b78    or          r31,r1,r1
0x1ffe574  3d200200    lis         r9,512
0x1ffe578  3ba9bef8    addi        r29,r9,-16648
0x1ffe57c  7fa803a6    mtspr       LR,r29
value = 33547648 = 0x1ffe580 = function3 + 0x28
->
-> *0x1ffe578
function3 + 0x20 = 0x1ffe578: value = 1000980216 = 0x3ba9bef8
-> *0x1ffe578 = 0x3ba9bc10
function3 + 0x20 = 0x1ffe578: value = 1000979472 = 0x3ba9bc10
-> *0x1ffe578
function3 + 0x20 = 0x1ffe578: value = 1000979472 = 0x3ba9bc10
->
-> function3
function1 called
mock function2 called
value = 0 = 0x0
->
```

Obviously, directly manipulating pointers in memory is going to quickly become tedious. Additionally, memory protection will prevent you from changing RTPs or objects loaded in VxSim. (Hence, why I ran this on actual hardware.) I mention the possibility, primarily because it seems to best match your question's statement.

Finally, for non-trivial unit testing, you may want to consider a tool designed specifically for the task. Try a search on "vxworks unit test framework". I don't have deep experience with any particular tool (and don't want to come across spammy). Perhaps, someone else here can provide a good suggestion.